# Only record while I am moving the mouse or typing

Tags: recordmydesktop

I'd like to have the resulting video as small as possible. So it should only record when I type or move mouse. When I'm idle, it should not record.

Answer (score 1):

You could 1) decompose to frames, 2) delete identical frames (or too similar) 3) recompose to movie.

For:

1. Try `ffmpeg -i yourvideo.avi frame%06d.png`
2. I'd use imagemagick in a perl script
3. either ffmpeg or mencoder

Comment: Thank you for decomposition of the problem. So your solution assume that I will record avi video of everything. How big will be the video in about 2 hours? Do you know how timeconsuming are the individual steps? Isn't there some automatic tool that will watch for signals sent from keyboard and mouse and if one of them is not idle saves the frame? I don't need sound, the sequence of images is sufficient.